# Proof: if for each $v \in V$ there is an element $c_v \in K$ such that $g(v) = c_vf(v)$, then there is $c \in K$ for which $g = cf$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$V$ and $W$ are linear spaces over the field $K$ and $f, g : V → W$ are linear transformations.

Prove that if for each $v \in V$ there is an element $c_v \in K$ such that $g(v) = c_vf(v)$, then there is $c \in K$ for which $g = cf$

I find that proof interesting. As I understand the thing is: if for every vector in space $V$ there is an element in $K$ that makes two linear transformations equal for that particular vector then in that field, there is an element that makes those two linear transformations equal for every vector of field $K$. Is that correct? Can I have a hint for this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $u,v \in V$.  We want to show that $c_u=c_v$ (why?).  There's a trivial case where either $f=0$ or $g=0$ (the zero map), which I'll leave you to deal with.  So assume that $f$ and $g$ are non-trivial, and WLOG suppose $f(u),g(u)\neq 0$.

We know that $g(v) = c_v f(v)$, $g(u) = c_u f(u)$, and $$g(v+u) = c_{v+u} (f(v)+f(u)) = c_v f(v) + c_u f(u)$$
If $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are linearly independent, then the above implies $c_v = c_{v+u} = c_u$, as desired.

If $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are linearly dependent, then $f(v) = \lambda f(u)=f(\lambda u)$ for some $\lambda$.  So
$$
\begin{align*}
g(v) & = g(v-\lambda u + \lambda u) \\
& = g(v-\lambda u) + \lambda g(u) \\
& = c_{v-\lambda u} f(v-\lambda u) + \lambda c_u f(u) \\
& = 0 + c_u \lambda f(u) \\
& = c_u f(v)
\end{align*}
$$